# Datamining open source software alternatives

Tags: open-source, data-mining

I am evaluating datamining packages.

I have find these two so far:

[RapidMiner](http://rapid-i.com/content/blogcategory/38/69/)

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/)

Do you have any experience to share with these two products, or any other product to recommend me?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the yearly KDnuggets Polls 2007, 2008, and 2009, RapidMiner is the most widely used Open Source Data Mining Solution among data mining experts world-wide:
[KDnuggets Data Mining Tool Poll 2009](http://www.kdnuggets.com/polls/2009/data-mining-tools-used.htm)

RapidMiner is open source and 100% Java, RapidMiner is much more flexible and offers significantly more functionality than Weka and KNIME.

Regarding SVM implementations: Weka comes with one such implementation (LibSVM), while RapidMiner provides four SVM implementations (LibSVM, MySVM, EvoSVM, SMO-SVM), some of them with more advanced features.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative would be [Orange](http://magix.fri.uni-lj.si/orange/). It includes various algorithms and data mining techniques that you can access either directly through Python scripts or through GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Re-invent the wheel and code directly in R !

Comment: +1 for Laziness, Impatience, and Hubris.

Answer (score 2):

[Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/products/data_mining/) is a nice suit for Business Intelligence. So maybe you would like to take a look at it. I have some experience in it, mainly for data warehousing and was quite happy.

Comment: It seems like Pentaho is a major sponsor of Weka: http://weka.sf.net

Comment: Didn't know that. Maybe I have to re-view Weka.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in some **Java** code related to **frequent pattern mining, association rules and sequential pattern mining**,  I have a small open-source projects that has 42 algorithms related to these topics: http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/

However, please note that it does not provide any user interface. But it provides some very specialized algorithms that you will not find in other data mining packages.

Answer (score 1):

I have used **Weka** in a high school course, and it had a nice [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) implementation. This was 4 or 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

([KNIME](http://www.knime.org/) ) is fairly extensive data mining platform.

Answer (score 1):

According to the KDnuggets Poll 2011, RapidMiner once more is the most widely used data mining solution world-wide:
http://www.kdnuggets.com/2011/05/tools-used-analytics-data-mining.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), which is like WEKA except it is much much stronger on clustering and outlier detection, while WEKA essentially only does classification well.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, Pentaho is a powerful Business Intelligence suite which WEKA belong to.

So I'd also recommand Weka, just for the sake that you have a great solution to extend your application and a great community also.